# What is Regional Best in Shift 2 Unleashed?

Tags: need-for-speed-shift-2-unleashed

In autolog records of Shift 2 Unleashed, there are two record type: Regional Best and World Best. What does Regional Best mean? How do I know in which region I am?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most users say that we should read "National" instead of "Regional".

It's not great as a response, but it's [the best answer I could find](http://forum.ea.com/eaforum/posts/list/5605433.page#13467012).

Comment: It's typically best to include a short summary of the page you've linked. This way, your answer will still answer the question if the link happens to die.